# Как изменить <title> страницы через php?

Tags: php

есть сайт site.ru, к нему установлен алиас домена krd.site.ru
Название города, телефонов и прочей локальной информацией управляет php-код, прикрепляю.
Как сменить на krd.site.ru тег `<title>` через php?

```html
<?php 
   if (strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'krd.site.ru')      !== false)
   { echo "Краснодаре"; } 
   else { echo "Санкт-Петербурге";}
?>
```

Comment: передать значение title в переменной и вывести его в верстке `<title><?= $title ?></title>`

Comment: echo '<title>Краснодар</title>';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
if (strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'krd.site.ru')      !== false)
{ $title =  "Краснодаре"; }
else { $title =  "Санкт-Петербурге";}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title><?echo $title?></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Почему-то отображается только "Санкт-Петербурге"..

Comment: @QuickBrownFox Если Вы хотите вывести что-то другое вместе с "Санкт-Петербурге", просто добавьте это в тег `<title>` до или после содержимого тега `<?php ?>` в нём

Answer (score 1):

передать значение title в переменной и вывести его в верстке

```
<?php
       $title = '';
       if (strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'krd.site.ru')      !== false)
       { $title = "Краснодаре"; } 
       else { $title = "Санкт-Петербурге";}
?>
```

...

```
<title><?= $title ?></title>
```

Comment: Почему-то отображается только "Санкт-Петербурге"..